# Check joined entity from Twig in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I want to display a table with some entity relations from a Doctrine DQL query.

My "main" entity Lead has a relation with Tour like this:

```
class Lead {
  /**
   * @var integer $tourId
   * @ORM\Column(name="`tour_id`", type="integer")
   */
  private $tourId;

  /**
   * @var Tour $tour
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tour")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tour_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $tour;

  ...
}
```

And I get the data from DB with a Doctrine2 DQL:

```
SELECT l, c
FROM BuvMarketplaceBundle:Lead l '
JOIN l.client c
```

Note that I don't JOIN with Tour becouse not all Leads have a Tour associated, this field can be null.

Then I am printing like this:

```
{% for lead in leads %}
  {{ lead.id }}
  {% if lead.tour %}
    {{ lead.tour.name }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem comes where lead.tour has a numeric value, but this value does not exists in the tours table (because it has been deleted). I get the "Entity was not found." exception that refers to the lead.tour that does not exist in the DB.

I tried to check lead.tour with *is defined*, *is not null* but nothing works.

Twig is not supporting the cheking of types, so there is no basic function available to check lead.tour is object or similar.

Is there any way that can check an object from Twig or left join from the DQL?

Comment: I think you will need to go back to basics here.  It should not be possible to have lead point to a record that does not exist.  Attempting to delete a record in tour when a lead points to it should throw up an error.  Using doctrine:schema:update will generate the necessary sql constraints for you.  Likewise there is absolutely no need to have a tourId in your lead entity.  Doctrine 2 is an ORM system not a table gateway or active record.  Best to work through the manual and setup your model the way Doctrine 2 expects it.  Or use something besides Doctrine 2.

Comment: Thaks. Yes it is possible in my model to have this type of relation: Some records have an associated entity and others not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A left join will solve the problem of not all leads having a tour.

```
SELECT lead,tour
FROM BuvMarketplaceBundle:Lead lead
LEFT JOIN lead.tour tour
```

And as my comment indicates, in a properly setup Doctrine 2 model, it will not be possible for lead to point to a tour record that does not exist.